# Find missing dates between the given range in informatica

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a requirement where I need to find missing dates from the table using informatica. For example:-

Data present for below dates:-

```
2020-09-01,
2020-09-03,
2020-09-06,
2020-09-07
```

Here missing dates are:-

```
2020-09-02,
2020-09-04,
2020-09-05
```

I need to populate these missing dates into the target which will be flat file. Please help .

Comment: What is your underlying database?

Comment: Redshift database

Comment: Can someone also please help with above problem?

Answer (score 0):

Redshift doesn't have recursive CTEs or a convenient way to create a sequence.  If you have enough rows in your table, you can do something like this:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by date) - 1 as n
      from data
     ),
     d as (
      select d.date, lead(d.date) over (order by d.date) as next_date
      from data d
     )
select d + n * interval '1 day' as missing_date
from d join
     n
     on d + n * interval '1 day' < d.next_date;
```

The purpose of `n` is to generate a sequence of numbers.  There just have to be enough numbers to fill the gaps.

Comment: This recursive approach is not working in redshift.Could you please provide another approach to implement this in redshift.

Comment: @amangupta . . . There is no "recursive" in this query.

Comment: Is here date referring to column name in the table and data referring to Table name? I am confused in this as I had replaced all date whereever present with column name and data with table name. Please help as I am new to this.

Comment: @amangupta . . ..  `data` is the name of the table.  `date` is a column in that table.